# How to access an instance of Class A by a mutual variable type in Class B

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am trying to write a method in a `BankAccount` class that withdraws money from an account, with only two parameters, being "user" field of type `User` (which is a class that contains a `String username`, and a `String password`, and an `ArrayList<String> usernames`), and "amount" field of type double.

The `BankAccount` class has a `accountOwner` field of type User and an `availableFunds` field of type `double`. I am trying to figure out how to find/access an instance of a `BankAccount` class, via the user parameter which is of type `User`.

I am new to Java, and I don't understand how to call an instance of "BankAccount" only by a User type variable.

I've tried creating a new `BankAccount` instance, but I don't want to do this, because I am trying to access an already existing instance of `BankAccount`.

Here are the relevant methods and fields of the User class:

```
public class User {
    static ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }
```

BankAccount class:

```
public class BankAccount {

    private User accountOwner;
    private double availableFunds;

public double getFunds()
    {
        return availableFunds;
    }

public void deposit(double deposit)
    {
        availableFunds += deposit;
    }
```

This is the method that I have to try and write:

```
public void withdraw(User user, double withdrawal) throws UserException, FundsException
    {

    }
```

Basically, the user enters a User user and double withdrawal amount, I have to deduct the withdrawal amount from a BankAccount class that is referenced using the User user somehow.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial : https://teaching.shu.ac.uk/aces/mp/msc/banktutorials.htm

Comment: If you want to have access to `BankAccount` via `User` object, you have to declare a new field in your `User` class, say `BankAccount userAccount;`, and assign a value to it (assuming a user has only one bank account).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments, if it helps, I think I am supposed to establish that "accountOwner" of BankAccount is the same as the "username" of the User of the bank account.

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to map the user you passed to the bank account. To do this could use the username as a map key, e.g. like this:

```
Map<String, User> usersByName = new Hashmap<>();
Map<String, BankAccount> accountsByUsername = new Hashmap<>();
```

Then you fill the maps, e.g. like this:

```
BankAccount account = ...//you got it from somewhere
accountsByUsername.put( account.getUser().getUsername(), account);
```

When withdrawing you get the account via the user's name:

```
BankAccount account = accountsByUsername.get(user.getUsername());
```

Alternatively you could use the `User` as the map key directly, i.e. `Map<User, BankAccount>` but you'd have to meet a few requirements for this:

- Implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `User` which probably only use the `username` property
- Make all properties of `User` that are used in those 2 methods immutable - map keys should *not* be allowed to change

**Edit**:

In response to your question in a comment, here are 3 possibilities on how you could get the account if you only have the username but have a `Map<User, BankAccount>` or just a `Collection<BankAccount>`:

1. If you have a `Map<User, BankAccount>` you can do a lookup of the user first, i.e. 
   `User user = usersByName.get(username); BankAccount account = accountsByUser.get(user);`
2. Alternatively you could only use `username` in `User.equals()` (and `User.hashCode()`) and create a new `User` instance just for the lookup: 
   `BankAccount account = accountsByUser.get(new User(username));`
3. If you just have a `Collection<BankAccount>` you could iterate over all accounts and look for one whose owner's username matches. Using streams it might look like this:

```
BankAccount account = accounts.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getOwner().getUsername().equals(username))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I see a problem with your approach, as Map<User, BankAccount> won't work because a user can have multiple bank accounts. Still +1 for highlighting other things

Comment: Please review my answer and try to highlight if some errors, and then combination of both can work as solution

Comment: @Ravi that's true although the OP's method wouldn't work in that case anyways - if a user had multiple accounts which one would be used for the withdrawal?

Comment: Yes thats why i have suggested withdraw method should have one parameter as bank account and based on the user we can validate whether it is authorised or not, same is highlighted in my answer

Comment: @Ravi well, the OP didn't state that a user can have multiple accounts - in fact "This is the method that I have to try and write" indicates the method signature is given and can't be changed thus implicitly indicating a 1:1 relation between user and account.

Comment: in that case bank account class should not have anything like accountOwner, rather the user should have a property bank account,  and every code should be extensible and fluid and obviously OP is more concerned about the correct design according to OOPS principle because we all agree that it is no where near to a production ready code

Comment: @Ravi "I am new to Java" - I doubt he's concerned about design at all.  Assuming `User` and `BankAccount` are given (we have no information about that) he's probably just concerned about getting it done and understanding how it's done. That's not to say that design isn't important - it just seems more like an optional/nice-to-have thing at the current stage :)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments, not too sure I understand them, but I just had another question to ask that might help solving the problem.

Is there a way I can access a BankAccount object, where the BankAccount's "accountOwner" is the same as a User's "username"? "accountOwner is a User object if that helps.

Comment: @LawfulNeutral its very much possible, create a map with User object as the key and value as the bank account object, but for this u need to implement equals and hashcode, another solution is have key as something called userid and value as bank account object(username can also work if that is unique)

Comment: @LawfulNeutral well since `accountOwner` is of type `User` and `username` is of type `String` doing a direct lookup isn't really possible. Don't try to implement `User.equals()` so that it equals a string with the right contents because that could cause problems if the comparison is reversed. I'll add some possibilities of what you can do to my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

See visualise it with the real bank account opening,

1) You create a user, (verifies your kyc by submitting documents)
2) A bank account is created and one of the user who opened the account becomes the owner
3) You deposit the funds in bank account, withdraws it...etc

So, The withdraws operation should now from which account funds need to be withdrawn and which user is withdrawing it.

Now the withdraw method should validate whether user is correct owner of the account or not

```
//Create banaccount and user objects seperately

public void withdraw(BankAccount banAcc , User user, double withdrawal) throws UserException, FundsException
{
    if(!bankAcc.getUser()==user) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("User is not authorised to withdraw funds");
    }
    if(bankAcc.getAvailableFunds < withdrawal) {
        throw new FundsException("Insufficient funds");
    }
    bankAcc.setAvailableFunds(bankAcc.getAvailableFunds-withdrawal);
}
```